# Why are the attribute nodes missing in the geometry node editor?

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I've sculpted an object in Blender and wanted to play with the geo nodes and I'm very new to using geo nodes. In a few tutorials I followed there were some attribute nodes I couldnt find in the editor. How do you get these?

[image]

This is all I have

Comment: What particular attribute nodes are you looking for?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250576/blender-3-0-offical-release-get-rid-off-some-geonodes-that-were-in-3-0a-what-t

Answer (score 2):

Geometry Nodes [underwent a system change](https://code.blender.org/2021/08/attributes-and-fields/) with v3.0, switching from "attributes" to "fields". The tutorials you're talking about were probably made before that change had happened, so they're now mostly deprecated. Many tutorial makers re-did their older ones with the new system, but obviously not all. When looking for tutorials, try to take care it's relatively new—starting from mid-to-late 2021, iirc.

Comment: Thx a lot for the insight will make sure to check newer tutorials